# MATE: How to show additional existing keyboard layouts?

Tags: keyboard-layout, ubuntu-mate

In Ubuntu Mate 18.04.5 there exist keyboard layouts (in the files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`) that I simply cannot *Add* in the GUI where I configure my keyboard (`mate-keyboard-properties`). The layouts are not shown to me.

I'm looking to add `svorak_A5` from `./se`.

Is there a simple config switch that I can throw to make them visible, or am I forced to manually edit XML to expose them as selectable?

Comment: Could you please be more specific. What is your current Ubuntu (MATE?) version? Have you tried to open `mate-keyboard-properties`, then click *Add*  to add new layout? What is the name (or language and variant) of missed keyboard layout? Do you want to get typographic symbols or what? Have you tried to make right click on keyboard layout indicator on MATE Panel, then selecting *Show Keyboard Layout* to [view it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaUcr.png)?

Comment: @N0rbert: The XKB layouts are split into base ones and "extras". Most desktops only show the non-extras by default. In my answer I showed how you can make "extras" available in the GUI on standard Ubuntu. Do you know if MATE has some equivalent feature?

Comment: @N0rbert Yes: 1) 18.04.5 LTS 32-bit with Mate 1.20.1, 2) Yes, 3) Swedish (se) svorak_A5, 4) Not sure what getting typographic symbols means exactly, 5) No. I'll update the Q to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable extra keyboard layouts in MATE by executing the following command:

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general load-extra-items true
```

Then launch `mate-keyboard-properties` and add new layout *By country*, *Country* → *Sweden*, *Variants* → *Swedish Swedish (Dvorak A5)*:

[image: svorak_a5]

and click *Add*.

Comment: Worked instantly :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you had used Ubuntu with GNOME, this command would have fixed it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

I think MATE is different, but maybe there is some equivalent to `show-all-sources` in MATE's dconf settings. You may want to install `dconf-editor` and use it to browse around and search.

Comment: It seems we meet every time I ask about keyboards. Yes, that's probably the switch I had a vague memory of. Thanks, I'll check the editor out in the meantime.

Comment: @Andreas: I watch the `keyboard-layout` tag and a few similar tags, that's probably why. ;)

Comment: I looked around in the editor but couldn't find anything relevant. It works fine in Ubuntu desktop but didn't transfer to Mate.

Comment: You were right, it was in there somewhere. I probably looked straight at it at some point...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also want to edit /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml and base.xml if you have added any custom keyboard layouts.